# In Typescript force generic type parameter to satisfy the type constraints based upon function overload definitions

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-generics

The necessary code skeleton to simplify the problem is given below. Basically, there can be different type of `Source` objects. For simplicity, two types of sources are shown in the code below: `DirectSource` and `IndirectSource`. The function `sourceAdapter()` accepts the `Source` and other helper parameters.

In the example: if parameter `key` is missing the `Source` must be a `DirectSource`; if `key` is a single string value then `Source` must be an `IndirectSource`, and in both cases the code performs necessary adjustments and returns a `DirectSource` object. If `key` is an array, the `Source` is supposed to be `IndirectSource` which is also the return value of the function.

---

```
type KeyMap<T> = { [key in keyof T]: number };

type DirectSource = {
  value: number;
  otherFieldsAndMethods: any;
};

type IndirectSource<T extends object> = {
  kvMap: KeyMap<T>;
  otherFieldsAndMethods: any;
};

type Source<T extends number | object> = T extends object ? IndirectSource<T> : DirectSource;

// overloads
function sourceAdapter(src: Source<number>): DirectSource;
function sourceAdapter<T extends object>(src: Source<T>, key: keyof T): DirectSource;
function sourceAdapter<T extends object>(src: Source<T>, key: (keyof T)[]): IndirectSource<T>;

function sourceAdapter<T extends number | object>(
  src: Source<T>,
  key?: keyof T | (keyof T)[]
): T extends object ? IndirectSource<T> : DirectSource {

  if (key) { // According to function overloads Source must be an IndirectSource
    if (key instanceof Array) { // Config and return IndirectSource
      const kvMap = key.reduce((ac, s) => {
        ac[s] = (src as any).kvMap[s];
        return ac;
      }, {} as any);

      // ******Error here:
      // Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'.
      let ret: IndirectSource<T> = {
        kvMap,
        otherFieldsAndMethods: src.otherFieldsAndMethods
      };
      return ret;
    } else { // Config and return DirectSource
      let directSource = {
        otherFieldsAndMethods: src.otherFieldsAndMethods,
        value: (src as IndirectSource<any>).kvMap[key],
      };
      return directSource; // ******Error here: assignability
    }
  } else { // Source is a DirectSource, simply return the src.
    return src;
  }
}
```

---

The lines where errors result are marked with stars. [This is the link to the playground.](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIFkCGYA8AVAfFAvFA3lANoDW8UAlgHZRkgD2AZlOgLoBcUVArgLYBGEAE5QAvgG4AUJNCQoAEQpCIAY2ABletyEroefJKhQAbkgA23CJx4DhUo-WAALYQDEKEMwBMAzgEEqLwQIZ3pfTiQqECkJaVloAElApVUNLR0IDCgIAA9gCECfKHp+ACtU7H1DWmNkME44RBQMTHti5zcPb39A4NDwqEjoyViZcGhNbV0s3PzCrj5BEQAfYrKK3BZsvILfNfK1KAB+KCSvFLVJjJaoTkVlS-TdKUkAelfi42EzeiRfSUY3Coago9BoPieED8XhQ+SEAAofDpOFdpjYlpgAJR3C5pKYQKSA4HAUHgyHQ2HCGY7eYlA7ATCI5FQVGZLAAGlo8E4dCYLGxClxrMJQJBYKgEPxFLAcOpcz2dIqTJUKMhLU5dE48N5zHQmKIrAFZyFaqwLyJYrJUphMqp6G28qK6OEUFWirUjOqSJVLNNmHZ1ToRx58D59tW2tDuv1rEkAvts12RXdwGOp2SDzx1ywt0FmdZBGkRgozEjIExBCg7ygfhUKnoQnOVAA5lBgPQoBaSeL6F8hD8-kUC7xuD5U4JBjRjfnIdVi6W6JQqGPIro+X4hEIkOXK9WAMJgxgUVuRLxQZTAbRTjOpVlzoxQevL1MkWooTZ0AB0yi83F08PhJAVE5HwKxwbADAfKDBhUIgfFYTZlUGIohkxT9XzqODWDaaDzxCK8YJwh9RE5fBRGQydyxeXDqwAUU3BsoBcZR2HvIxq3QcYoAAcnQbioC8egICdRwJSQEkfEYEA2xcR8wTHLdqFTbiU24z82KgMwQjw4BOGnW8-U2SDcJqOoAxM9pmPcTxfACIIQicMIfE4b1P0cKyuls3oHKcjTYlwi8CIvIjyM8HxoEIfdD2PScz0CoQaHuAz8Q0rTU3OGd8SMjSHA6IRrO6Oy+kcgZXPczobJ6ez+h8cyTNMCwrCgJCkCKfTHnxVAhixdC3zAUh4FYOqoP86D4poDLkoycQqw+eihEY5imtanxjyoJB+AoMwKFAe9RGqUKzHC3cPgLCgULzKbdBAiheDAMxpPGmToFc+8nu9Np9v2oA)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest cleanest way is just to change the ReturnType to a union. Enjoy.
[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIFkCGYA8AVAfFAvFA3lANoDW8UAlgHZRkgD2AZlOgLoBcUVArgLYBGEAE5QAvgG4AUJNCQoAEQpCIAY2ABletyEroefJKhQAbkgA23CJx4DhUo-WAALYQDEKEMwBMAzgEEqLwQIZ3pfTiQqECkJaVloAElApVUNLR0IDCgIAA9gCECfKHp+ACtU7H1DWmNkME44RBQMTHti5zcPb39A4NDwqEjoyViZcGhNbV0s3PzCrj5BEQAfYrKK3BZsvILfNfK1KAB+KCSvFLVJjJaoTkVlS-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-IyBSlJ7c4h0hTZ-x0hzOlMnoLP6GyJR0eyOiEEzunMvorN8AydNMCwrCgCCkCKPy42mIYsVgm8wFIeBWDqgCPMA2KaDSjSMnEfMPlIoRyMoprWp8TcqCQfgKDMChQCC6pgrMULlw+VMKCgwV0vxL8KF4MAzCEsbhOgOzTwe902lEEYgA)

```
type KeyMap<T> = { [key in keyof T]: number };

type DirectSource = {
  value: number;
  otherFieldsAndMethods: any;
};

type IndirectSource<T extends object> = {
  kvMap: KeyMap<T>;
  otherFieldsAndMethods: any;
};

type Source<T extends number | object> = T extends object ? IndirectSource<T> : DirectSource;

// overloads
function sourceAdapter(src: Source<number>): DirectSource;
function sourceAdapter<T extends object>(src: Source<T>, key: keyof T): DirectSource;
function sourceAdapter<T extends object>(src: Source<T>, key: (keyof T)[]): IndirectSource<T>;
function sourceAdapter<T extends object>(
  src: Source<T>,
  key?: keyof T | (keyof T)[]
): IndirectSource<T> | DirectSource {

  if (key) { // According to function overloads Source must be an IndirectSource
    if (key instanceof Array) { // Config and return IndirectSource
      const kvMap = key.reduce((ac, s) => {
        ac[s] = (src as any).kvMap[s];
        return ac;
      }, {} as any);

      // Error here:
      // Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'.
      let ret: IndirectSource<T> = {
        kvMap,
        otherFieldsAndMethods: src.otherFieldsAndMethods
      };
      return ret as IndirectSource<T>;
    } else { // Config and return DirectSource
      let directSource = {
        otherFieldsAndMethods: src.otherFieldsAndMethods,
        value: (src as IndirectSource<any>).kvMap[key],
      };
      return directSource; // Error here: assignability
    }
  } else { // Source is a DirectSource, simply return the src.
    return src;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Shannon that would not even compile, please use the playground and test yourself. Also, if you use `any` or union types everywhere it would work, but that would defeat the purpose of Type system.

Comment: You on typescript 3.3.3? - Added playground link

Comment: Sometimes type assertions or the like (e.g., wide overload implementation signature) are the best we can do.  A function that returns a generic conditional type tends to make the *caller's* life easier, but the *implementer's* life harder.  The compiler can't easily verify assignability to an unresolved generic conditional, so you are usually forced to use assertions.

Comment: ^ What jcalz said is true, a function in it's simplest form is just a mapping between two categories of types, the input type mapped to the output type a function is not multiple mappings between multiple categories, try and avoid overloads as they are an anti pattern.

Comment: Okay, I see why it worked for you. From function signature, you removed the  <T extends number | object> and replaced with <T extends object>. But, my main question relates to that. How can we narrow down the type generic type constraint in code. I will have to check whether this type of workaround will solve my original problem or not.